# Dax How to get distinct values from a column

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax

This is the query I'm trying.

```sql
EVALUATE
SELECTCOLUMNS('MyTable',"col1",DISTINCT(VALUES('MyTable'[Email])))
```

Comment: I think `VALUES` by itself should already produce a distinct list.

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to simply create a new, single column table with the distinct values of an existing table, you can use the formula below.

Starting with data like this...

[image: Data]

... simply create a new table with this formula to get a list of distinct values.

```
Locations = DISTINCT(Fruit[Location])
```

[image: Distinct]

Comment: In my example, yes `VALUES` will return the same results. According to the documentation, the functions are different and could return different results (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634547.aspx#Anchor_3))

Comment: Yes just the values by itself works but if I have to put the values inside the selectcolumns it doesnot seem to work, as I have to select multiple columns  here.

Comment: @genie Are you looking for a table with 2+ columns with all distinct combinations from the source columns?

Comment: @Joe: Yes Joe i want to select more than one columns from different tables.

Comment: @genie: In that case, can you edit your question with more details? Preferably, show a diagram of your tables (and how they relate) and specify which columns you want in the distinct list (since you only have one in your question right now).

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
Evaluate

VALUES('Table'[Column])
```

Comment: This only works as an intermediate function within a formula. If you want a new column then you have to make a new table.